# Build an MRCP client which communicates with Nuance speech server

Tags: unimrcp

- Download and install the installation packages from 
  http://www.unimrcp.org/:
  -unimrcp-sdk-1.0.0.exe and unimrcp-sdk-1.0.0.exe (32-bit)   OR
  -unimrcp-x64-sdk-1.0.0.exe and unimrcp-x64-1.0.0.exe (64-bit)
- Download the file nuance-unimrcp-sample-client-1.0.zip from Nuance Network.
- Set up your building environment:
  a. Unzip nuance-unimrcp-sample-client-1.0.zip to a location accessible and convenient for your build setup.
  b. Include directory: \include.
  c. Add files apr_xml.h and apu.h provided under ..\nuance-unimrcp-sample-client-1.0\include to the UniMRCP include folder \include. The default location is C:\Program Files\UniMRCP\include.
  d. Preprocessor definitions required: WIN32, APT_STATIC_LIB, MPF_STATIC_LIB & MRCP_STATIC_LIB.
  e. Additional library directories: \lib.
  f. Dependencies=
  -mrcp.lib
  -mpf.lib
  -aprtoolkit.lib 
  -libaprutil-1.lib
  -libapr-1.lib
  -libunimrcpclient.lib
  -mrcpsofiasip.lib
  -mrcpunirtsp.lib
  -unirtsp.lib
  -mrcpclient.lib
  -mrcpv2transport.lib
   -mrcpsignaling.lib
   -libsofia_sip_ua.lib
  -ws2_32.lib
  -winmm.lib    g. Add source file ..\unimrcp-sample-client\src\unimrcp-sample-client.c in the project.
- Compile UniMRCP Sample Client as a console application.
- 5 Run UniMRCP Sample Client.

These are the steps given to build a console application.I have all the files available. I linked the header files to the source code but am a little confused as to how to proceed next. How to link all these files together?